# How to convert vector of bytes into lines and store as string

Tags: c++, file, io

I want to process a large text file line by line. I have found some code that looks to be very fast when reading a file:

```
std::vector<std::byte> load_file(std::string const& filepath)
{
  std::ifstream ifs(filepath, std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);

  if(!ifs)
    throw std::runtime_error(filepath + ": " + std::strerror(errno));

  auto end = ifs.tellg();
  ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

  auto size = std::size_t(end - ifs.tellg());

  if(size == 0) // avoid undefined behavior
    return {};

  std::vector<std::byte> buffer(size);

  if(!ifs.read((char*)buffer.data(), buffer.size()))
    throw std::runtime_error(filepath + ": " + std::strerror(errno));

  return buffer;
}
```

Now the problem is, I do not know how to use this to read lines of the file.

This is a solution I came up with.... but somehow it looks very bad or inefficient! Is there any better way to do this, or the `load_file` function is just not made to do this job as in reading lines from a text file?

```
  auto fileConent = load_file(R"(C:\analysis\simple.txt)");

  auto line = vector<std::byte>();
  for(const auto& byte : fileConent) {
    if(static_cast<char>(byte) != '\n') {
      line.push_back(byte);
    } else {
      std::cout
          << std::string_view(reinterpret_cast<char*>(line.data()), line.size())
          << std::endl;
      line.clear();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `std::getline`?

Comment: If it's a text file (which is implied since you talk about _lines_) then why open it in binary mode and store it in a `std::vector<std::byte>`? You could just store the file in a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: don't use code you found somewhere when you do not understand what it was written for.

Comment: the question you should ask is "How to read lines from a text file?"

Comment: btw `std::cout <<` is slow. You do not need the most efficient way to read from a file when then anyhow you write to `stdout`. Writing to `stdout` is slow, but still much faster than any human can read

Comment: How many gigabytes  is "large"?

Comment: Since you are apparently happy to use `std::string_view` then why not read the whole file into a `std::string` instead of `std::vector` and then create a `std::string_view` for each line referencing the `std::string` containing the whole file?

Comment: @john well I would do that if I knew how :D

Comment: @DEKKER Well in your `load_file` function you could literally replace `std::vector<std::byte>` with `std::string`.

Comment: @DEKKER And in your remaining code it's just a matter of replacing your range based loop with a regular for loop. All you need to make a `std::string_view` is a pointer to the beginning of the line and the length of the line. That shouldn't be too hard to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a reference to the term *fast*, then you will often read comments like:

- Did you compile in release mode with all optimizations on?
- What is a big file and what is a large number of lines?

So, first, please make sure that you compile your program with all speed optimizations on. Then, please understand, 1'000'000 lines are considered small nowadays.

---

Regarding the shown source code:

Your first code example simply reads the the file into a `std::vector`of `std::bytes`. It does this by trying to read the file size and then using the very fast `read`-function of the `std::ifstream`.

This will work and will be fast, but will not help you, because you need lines.

The second code snippet analyzes the the `std::vector` that was read before and prints a line after each '\n' has been found. This is basically OK. But, the `std::string_view`s are not stored. Maybe this solution is sufficient for you.

---

Anyway, there are some comments.

- Your method to detect the file size is not safe. Please use the `file_size`-function from the  `<filesystem>` instead
- You can boost the read operation by providing a bigger input buffer with the `pubsetbuf`-function of the `std::ifstream`s `streambuf`

Using not optimized stream functions like `std::getline` or `std::istringstream` will not help. This will be much much slower.

To show to you what can be achieved, I created a test file with 50'000'000 lines. The resulting size was 1.5GB for my test.

Please see the example ocde below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem>
#include <random>
#include <string_view>

struct Timer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> startTime{};
    long long elapsedTime{};
    void start() { startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }
    void stop() { elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime).count(); }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Timer& t) { return os << t.elapsedTime << " ms "; }
};

constexpr size_t NumberOfRows =      50'000'000U;
constexpr size_t NumberOfRowsGuess = 60'000'000U;
constexpr int MinLineLength = 10;
constexpr int MaxLineLength = 30;

const std::string testDataFileName{ "r:\\test.txt" };

void createTestFile() {
    static std::random_device rd{};
    static std::mt19937 gen{ rd() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> uniformDistributionStringLength(MinLineLength, MaxLineLength);

    if (std::ofstream testDataStream(testDataFileName); testDataStream) {
        Timer t1; t1.start();
        for (size_t row{}; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
            testDataStream << row << ' ' << std::string(uniformDistributionStringLength(gen), 'a') << '\n';
        }
        t1.stop(); std::cout << "\nDuration for test file creation: " << t1 << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Could not open file '" << testDataFileName << "' for writing.\n\n";
}


constexpr std::size_t IOBufSize = 5'000'000u;
static char ioBuf[IOBufSize];


int main() {
    //createTestFile();

    if (std::ifstream ifs{ testDataFileName,std::ios::binary }; ifs) {

        Timer tOverall{}; tOverall.start();

        // To speed up reading of the file, we will set a bigger input buffer
        ifs.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(ioBuf, IOBufSize);

        // Here we will store the complete file, all data
        std::string text{};

        // Get number of bytes in file
        const std::uintmax_t size = std::filesystem::file_size(testDataFileName);
        text.resize(size);

        // Read the whole file with one statement. Will be ultrafast
        Timer t; t.start();
        ifs.read(text.data(), size);
        t.stop(); std::cout << "Duration for reading complete file:\t\t" << t << "\t\tData read: " << ifs.gcount() << " bytes\n";

        // Creating a vector with string views and reserve memory. Make a big guess
        std::vector<std::string_view> lines{}; 
        lines.reserve(NumberOfRowsGuess);

        // Create the string views with the lines
        char* start{ text.data() };
        char* end{start};
        std::size_t index{};

        t.start();
        for (const char c : text) {
            ++end;
            if (c == '\n') {
                lines.push_back({start, end });
                start = end;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\nNumber of lines Read: " << lines.size() << '\n';

        t.stop(); std::cout << "Duration for creating all string views:\t\t" << t << '\n';
        tOverall.stop(); std::cout << "\n\nDuration overall:\t\t\t\t" << tOverall << '\n';
    }
    else std::cout << "\n\nError: Could not open test file '" << testDataFileName << "'\n\n";
}
```

---

I tested the program on my 12 years old Windows 7 machine.

Program output was:

```
Duration for reading complete file:             752 ms          Data read: 1538880087 bytes

Number of lines Read: 50000000
Duration for creating all string views:         1769 ms


Duration overall:                               2966 ms
```

This should be "sufficiently" *fast*.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pass the buffer to an `std::istringstream` and read lines from that instead of implementing it yourself.

Of course, you could also skip the function and read lines from `std::ifstream` directly.